# User cannot facebook log in again if they've deleted the facebook app in the past. Issue only arises from ios6.0 facebook integration

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook authorization fails on iOS6 when switching FB account on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device)

So I have found that if a user deletes my app using facebook web settings and then tries to login in again using ios 6.0 facebook integration they get the following error below.

This is only if they are using iOS 6.0 facebook integration. They can relog into the app if they are not using facebook integration (and simply using the old fashion log in procedure).

Can anyone else reproduce this?

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x155326b0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 190;
            message = "The access token was invalidated on the device.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

Comment: Hey Alex. I'm facing the same problem here. Did you solve your question?

Comment: Yes I did find a solution, you can see it in the comment above. It did end up working for me.