# Facebook iOS SDK won't open login UI after user changes password (iOS 6)

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

Some context: the user had previously installed the app, authorized FB, everything worked great, then they changed their FB password (through facebook.com), deleted the app, and have now reinstalled it and are running it for the first time again after reinstall.

I am calling `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler]` with `allowLoginUI: YES` and the read permissions being "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_interests, user_location."

The `FBSessionState` I am getting in the `completionHandler` is `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed`. The NSLog of the error is this:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1cd68c00 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password." UserInfo=0x1cd5b970 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.}}

That internal error domain is `ACErrorDomain` and error code `ACErrorPermissionDenied`. So, how do I let the user re-authorize the app?

I have tried calling `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` again but that just keeps outputting the same error. I have also tried `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]` but that doesn't seem to do anything (presumably because there is no `activeSession`).

Comment: I am running into a very similar situation except I am getting into FBSessionStateOpen in my completion handler except the session.accessTokenData.accessToken is invalid!  The only way I can clear the problem is to go to the Settings App, type in the new password (even though there is no indication that it is wrong) disable access to the app, try a login, fail, go back to settings and re-enable access to the app, try and finally succeed.  Terrible.  Hoping I can find a better fix.  Wondering if it is an OS bug.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  Was anyone able to figure this out?

Comment: I have the same issue. Anyone has a solution here? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Hitting a very similar sort of bug with 3.2.1 Facebook SDK.  In my case, I get into FBSessionStateOpen but have been given an invalid access token.  As the question states, the normal closeAndClearTokenInformation and even deleting the app doesn't fix it.  The only way I have been able to get-back-in under this scenario is to have the user change their password in the setting app.  So this is what I do.

```
// In my completion handler FBSessionStateOpen is called BUT an
// invalid accessToken was detected.

[session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, 
                                    NSError *error) 
  {
     if (result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed ||
         result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected)
     {
       [self showErrorMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"You may need to re-enter your Facebook password in the iPhone Settings App.\n", nil)];
     }
     else 
     {
        // attempt opening a session again  (after they have updated their account 
        // settings I end up here)

        [self facebookLogin];  // Performs openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions, 
                               // but this time around the token issued should be good.
     }
 }];
```

This is the only pragmatic solution I have been able to come up with.

Comment: This is not a actual solution as the UI for login is still no presented. Did you find something that works UI wise or you just present a message to the user?

Comment: I took the above approach.  In my case, use had changed the fb password but had not updated the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get a new access token with code like this...

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[[FBSession class] performSelector:@selector(renewSystemAuthorization)];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

}
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't seem to work. I do get the "Facebook: Blah app would like to access your profile" alert view on the iPhone, but it just ends up returning the same NSError. I had also tried the method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device/12863036#12863036) which looks to be the same as FBSession's `renewSystemAuthorization` with no success.