# Different Facebook accounts Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I just start the integration of Facebook on my Iphone app.

I can log and get my profile picture and my name, but when i try to switch for another account (not my developer account), i get this error :

```
FBLoginView encountered an error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)"
```

i obviously already search on internet but don't find any solution, so I really don't know how to fix that  :/

thx for your help !

**[EDIT] : In fact, my app on the Facebook developer account was in 'SandBox mode' so, only developers and testers could launch this app on their iPhone !!**

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691444/facebook-sdk-3-1-1-ios-6-1-login-error

Comment: Yes i saw it, but i use a FBLoginView, so i dont use openSessionWithAllowLoginUI and others FBSession methods :/