# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.) ios6

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-login

Hi i am ussing ios6 for facebook login and i am getting this error as native popup

The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)

This is the scenario ive used. (**I am running this on simularor**)

I have logged in to the facebook app through settings and  i tried to login to my app and its working fine.

Then i logged out of the facebook from settings and logged in again with different user. Then i tried to login to the app. I am getting this error.

I tried loging out of the app using the command

`[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];`

But no use.

The bundle identifier in the facebook app is same as in my ios app.

this is the code i used to login

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
```

Any help is appreciated.

This is the error i am getting

> Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
>   (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x9535330 
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate:  (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
>   0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000,  permissions:(null)>}

**NOTE**
I got the same error on a different occation. At that time it was a bug in my code

Instead of giving permission as

`NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email",@"birthday", nil];`

i was wrongly doing it as

`NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email,birthday", nil];`

**SOLUTION**
Even after correcting the code, I was getting the same error. I have to logout and login the facebook from ios settings screen. Once i did that the correct code never caused any problem. Note that the problem only occured on the device that previously executed the buggy code. Note sure what caused the problem, 
Hope this info helps someone

Comment: The following link solved my problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device

Thanks,

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

- Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
- Open your Facebook Settings
- Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook
  interaction.

This could happen on any device, therefore in your app you will have to make sure to handle this error correctly.
I reckon you give the user feedback why Login With Facebook failed and ask the user to check  their Facebook settings on their device.

```
 - (void)facebookSessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // handle successful login here
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            if (error) {
                // handle error here, for example by showing an alert to the user
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not login with Facebook"
                                                                message:@"Facebook login failed. Please check your Facebook settings on your phone."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: The alert view should be wrapped in an if (error) {} block, right now the alert will show every time the user logs out, when really, it only needs to show when there's an error.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

check your Bundle identifier for your project and you give Bundle identifier for your app which create on developer.facebook.com that they are same or not.

Comment: This solved the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device

Comment: @coolcool1994: It's not the App ID.  It's the "Bundle ID" under the "Native iOS App" section of the Facebook app's "Basic Info".

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the Bundle ID check is case sensitive.

Answer (score 8):

Another potential cause for this error: Attempting to get permission for a Facebook app in sandbox mode when the Facebook user is not listed in the app's admins, developers or testers.

Answer (score 3):

I solve my problem by passing nil permission while login.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. the error comes up when the i switched the fb user from setting. [Facebook authorization fails on iOS6 when switching FB account on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device) This solved my problem

Comment: Please consider adding *which part* of that question solved your problem. It contains three answers, non of which have been checked as being the accepted one. Simply pointing broadly to another question as an answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and took a whole day to figure out the problem. This error message by Facebook SDK is very vague. I had this problem due to openURL: method being overwritten in MyApplication. I removed the overwritten method and facebook login worked fine.

Comment: Did you make sure to implement `openURL:` with a call to return `[FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];` ? This is required by the Facebook SDK to work properly, but as long as you do this, you should still be able to implement openURL for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was invalid permissions - I was requesting "birthday" instead of "user_birthday". It's a shame the error message isn't at least minimally descriptive - just saying "permissions invalid" rather than ERROR CODE 2 would have saved me so much time.