# Facebook login using Parse not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to use Parses SDK to make the single sign on for Facebook but when I press the login button I get this error:

> Uh oh. An error occurred: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)"
>   UserInfo=0x1d5bac20
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

The code when I hit the button is almost the same as in [Parse's tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios)

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler {
    // The permissions requested from the user
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_birthday"];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        }
    }];
}
```

I have my facebook app all set and everything.

Any leads?

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831610/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-com-facebook-sdk-error-2-ios6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem on my device. Same error.

Fix was simple: Settings -> Privacy -> Facebook -> and check your app status there.

Comment: You need to do this on your device (iPhone/Simulator)

Comment: for those who are still getting the error, check if the bundle id of the app is the same entered at the facebook app.

Comment: Fantastic. Somehow, the privacy setting was 'off' and that caused the error. Must warn the user about that...!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on one device (iPhone 5S). The Settings -> Privacy -> Facebook were correct.
I had other devices along with the iPhone sim which all worked fine.

Anyway, I tried rebooting which did not fix the issue, also to delete the app and reinstall.

**What finally worked was the following:**

1. Turn off the access for the app under Settings -> Privacy ->
   Facebook.
2. Try logging into FB from the app. (which fails of course).
3. Re enable access for the app setting under Settings -> Privacy ->
   Facebook.
4. Try logging into FB from the app which now succeeded.

Strange error.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer below. Sometimes strangely enough the switch is turned on. It helps to relogin with Facebook in System preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an empty permissions array NSArray *permissionsArray = @[];

Make sure your permissions are set in your facebook app console.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my FB access Key and secret from the parse backend and it worked great.

( Parse bug??)

Answer (score 0):

Please makesure you for add at AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

     return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

and add

```
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on **Swift 3.1** and **iOS 10.3.1**, make sure that you have following methods in your app delegate:

**Just for Swift 3.1:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
       $0.applicationId = "XXXXX"
       $0.clientKey = "XXXXXX"
       $0.server = "https://yourserverparse.."
   }

   Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
   PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

And than:

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    var isHandled:Bool;

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        isHandled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[.annotation])
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        isHandled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

    return isHandled
}
```

And than:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```