# FB login is does not working when i already loggedin device setting iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I already logged in device settings and then i am accessing my Facebook feature its not loading albums, its returning session state as 513 , and while trying to get albums its returning 190 error code. 190 indicates  "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token".

If i delete the account from device setting and if i again logging in, then its working fine. I am facing this issue only very first time installation of app that too if i already logged in device setting.What could be the reason? can any one help me on this? Please find below code ..that i have written ..

```
/*
 * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
 */

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI WithSuccessBlock:(FacebookAuthSuccessBlock)fbSuccessBlock andFailureBlock:(FacebookAuthFailureBlock)fbFailureBlock
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    if (fbSuccessBlock != nil)
    {
        fbAuthSuccessBlock = fbSuccessBlock;
    }

    if (fbFailureBlock != nil)
    {
        fbAuthFailureBlock = fbFailureBlock;
    }

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            USER_PHOTOS,
                            READ_STREAM,
                            FRIENDS_PHOTOS,
                            nil];

    FBSession  *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:FB_APP_ID permissions:permissions
                                           urlSchemeSuffix:@"Sample"
                                        tokenCacheStrategy:nil];


    if (allowLoginUI ||
        (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded))
    {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
        {
             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];
        result = session.isOpen;
    }

    return result;
}


//////
//Facebook Settings
/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        FRMLogInfo(@"*******state = %d*********", state);
        switch (state) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                if (!error)
                {
                    // We have a valid session
                    fbAuthSuccessBlock();

                }
                break;

            case FBSessionStateClosed:
                [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                break;

            case 2:
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            {
                if (fbAuthFailureBlock)
                {
                    fbAuthFailureBlock();
                }
            }
                break;

            default:
                FRMLogInfo(@"Some thing else.....");
                break;
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
         object:session];

        if (error)
        {

            FRMLogInfo(@"error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            [BlockAlertView multiButtonAlert:NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"FB_ERROR_TITLE", nil, [[LocalizationHelper sharedLocalizationHelper] localizationBundle], @"")
                                     message:NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"FB_ERROR_MSG", nil, [[LocalizationHelper sharedLocalizationHelper] localizationBundle], @"")
                                       style:UIAlertViewStyleDefault
                                 cancelTitle:@"OK"
                                 cancelBlock:^{

                                 }
                                  otherTitle:nil
                                 otherBlocks:nil];
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device

Comment: @NitinGohel Hi , The link which u have given is different from my Question , In that he is facing problem when he changing accounts , But i dont have problem with changing accounts. Its working perfectly after changing multiple times with multiple accounts . Because when i login with new account the previous token is refreshing with new token and its working fine, but very first time if i have old token and if i directly access Facebook login its giving problem, may be token is expired here. So if i login again its working.

Comment: Any one faced this issue before ?