# iOS Facebook SDK Error 2

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I've just activated my Apple Developer program and I was trying my app on different devices. I tried first on my iPad and it worked without error, then I decided to try on my sister's iPod Touch so I set the iOS Device on Apple Developer Website and I ran the app, when I tried to login an error compared: "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)".

I googled all the evening, everything seems ok, the Bundle ID is set in Facebook Developers page and it's the same of the XCode project, the sandbox mode is disabled so it would have worked correctly but this doesn't happend! I tried everything but the error is still there. :(

The strange thing is that on the simulator and on my iPad works, but on my sister's iPod not.
Do you have some idea on how to solve this problem? :\

My code on openSession method (login) is really simple so I don't think there are some problem here, however, this is it:

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"rsvp_event", nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                          FBSessionState state,
                                                          NSError *error) {
                                                              [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                                  state:state
                                                                                  error:error];
                                                          }];
```

I'm using iOS7 and Facebook SDK 3.9, help me please and thanks for your answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try logout the facebook account from Settings. And login again from Settings.

Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device), maybe you are in the same scenario.