# Facebook iOS SDK - Login process shuts down my application running in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I am using Facebook SDK 3.13 for iOS in one of my apps. Everything works like a charm on any simulator. However there is a problem with Facebook Login on device.

When I click "Facebook Login" button, a Safari window opens. While it is loading facebook.com, my app -running in the background- shuts down. During debugging, XCode clarifies this situation with an error tells the application is "Terminated due to memory pressure". Therefore session handler never calls any completion method (and never fires an exception) and no session is opened. So when I close Safari window, my app runs from scratch - does not continue from where was it.

How may I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the instruments to see are you using memory. Maybe post the code your using too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657780/ios-facebook-sdk-error-domain-com-facebook-sdk-code-2-and-code-7

try this dude