# Facebook SDK for iOS permissions trouble

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm having some trouble with the Facebook permissions.

Normally I'd use `basic_profile` and `email`, and this works find on my iPhone. However, when using the simulator, I get an error saying that I should use `public_profile` and `user_friends` instead of `basic_profile`. I changed these, and now it works in the simulator. Switching back to my iPhone creates problems though, as I get an error. It looks like this:

```
1. An error occurred: 
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk 
Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" 
UserInfo=0x170470700 {
  com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, 
  com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error 
  Domain=com.apple.accounts 
  Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)",         
  com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x17030c330, state:   
  FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, 
  loginHandler: 0x0, 
  appID: **appID**, 
  urlSchemeSuffix: , 
  tokenCachingStrategy:<PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy: 0x178229180>,  
  expirationDate: (null), 
  refreshDate: (null), 
  attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, 
  permissions:(null)>
}
```

I'm using **Parse**, and this is how I set up the permissions:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends", @"email"];
  [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Facebook SDK Error Domain com.facebook.sdk Code 2 and Code 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657780/ios-facebook-sdk-error-domain-com-facebook-sdk-code-2-and-code-7)

Comment: @TimothyWalters nope, that question/answer doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. What version of the sdks are you using?

Comment: @truthful_ness the latest version

Comment: I got mine to work, I don't want to post it as a solution because maybe it was lucky. I started a new project (difference being is used ios 7.1sdk, previous project was ios 8). Also, make sure you have added your facebook AppId & secret to your parse account.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that!

Comment: I got a similar problem and removing `public_profile` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got mine to work- Pass it an empty permissions array.

NSArray *permissionsArray = @[];

However, make sure you have the permissions you want set up in my facebook app page. I only needed the default one so I was okay.

I have a feeling that facebook changed it's server side code. My app was working fine, and then my FB login broke.

Hope that helps!