# Login via facebook with system account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm doing login via facebook in one of my app.
For that I'm using `FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView` as `FBSession` behavior as per hierarchy is works fine in FB installed app, Safari but problem is in login with facebook system app.

**My code is as per below.**

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_friends"]];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                FBSessionState status,
                                NSError *error) {

                FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                                          parameters:@{}
                                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

                [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error){
                FBUserDetail=(NSArray*)result;
                NSLog(@"FBUSERDETAIL:%@",FBUserDetail);

                cricoFrndArray=[FBUserDetail valueForKey:@"data"];
                FBUserDetail=[FBUserDetail valueForKey:@"data"];

            }];
}];
```

As per this I am able to login via facebook installed app which is running well, even when user have not install facebook app it will go for facebook system account where I am getting error and if there is no facebook system account found then it will go for login via safari which is running well.

**Error is as follow.**

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x14da88c0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously." UserInfo=0x14dacf40 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously.}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

Comment: check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657780/ios-facebook-sdk-error-domain-com-facebook-sdk-code-2-and-code-7

Comment: there is no option for on or off

Comment: Now it is ON for myApp thought it is not working

Comment: Is your code snippet above complete? Are you asking for any permissions that's not represented above?

Comment: I think I wrote that it is working very fine when login via facebook app and safari.
It means there no error for asking permission
the permission which i required in app that is already mentioned here