# Is there any way to know whether the user log into Facebook through web or native login?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook SDK 3.2 on iOS.

I want to show a Logout button if the user log into Facebook through web and hide the Logout button if the user log in using the native login in Settings > Facebook.  Clicking the Logout button will close the Facebook session.

I cannot find any function in the Facebook SDK that can give me this information on where the user log in from.  Is this information provided by the SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a description of the login types in FBSession.h.

I wrote the following code to check for native login:

```
-(BOOL)isLoginUsingNativeFacebookLogin
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.loginType == FBSessionLoginTypeFacebookApplication || FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.loginType == FBSessionLoginTypeSystemAccount) {
        return YES;
    } 

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I don't sure it works. I have tested when logging with my facebook account in setting and this function always return NO. The answer for this question should be here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929776/recognize-if-user-has-defined-a-native-facebook-account-in-ios-6-settings]